# Isotope.js - WhiteSpace between element

Tags: jquery, image, grid, whitespace, jquery-isotope

I have used masonry.js in the past but I heared that Isotope.js is more flexible/better so I went and download it to make a grid image gallery.

My problem right now is that Isotope is leaving a little white space between elements before resizing (on page load).
After resizing, the element are changing size and the white space disapear, even if I go back to the original window size.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lByri

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $container =jQuery('.gallery-grid-container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: '.item'
        }
    });
});
```

There is no problem when I do it on codepen, only on my website.

(http://avetisthemes.com/photography/gallery-grid/)

How isotope work is that it takes the div width that you write in jQuery, and it places the element on the screen with a position:absolute, top and left value.

Example:
My image are 540x375
My div that englobe the image are 25% width. So 4 image in a row.

I will go with the second image on my row so you can understand the attribute part.
It gives a left attribute of 480px (on load), after resizing and going back to the original size, it gives a left attribute of 475px.

At 475px, the grid is perfect, but on load when it's at 480px it leaves a little white space that I would like not to have.

Thanks for any help!
-Antoine

Comment: please add a real example on jsfiddle or similar

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lByri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself.

It was a CSS issue, I only had to put `vertical-align:top` to my `.item` class.